# how to calculate the coordinates on a polyline perpendicular to point (in 3D)?

Tags: math, vector, geometry, language-agnostic, polyline

I have two approximately parallel polylines representing railway tracks, consisting of hundreds (maybe thousands) of x, y, z coordinates. The two lines stay approximately 1.435m apart, but bend and curve as a railway would.

If I pick a point on one of the polylines, how do find the point which is perpendicular on the other parallel polyline?

[image: This would be like using a perpendicular snap in a CAD program (shown here using FreeCAD).]

I take it CAD programs use the cross product to find the distance / point and it chooses the line to snap to based on where your mouse is hovering.

I would like to achieve the same thing, but without hovering your mouse over the line.

Is there a way to simply compute the closest line segment on the parallel line? Or to see which segment of the polyline passes through a perpendicular plane at the selected point?

It isn't practical to loop through the segments as there are so many of them.

In python the input would be something like point x, y, z on rail1 and I would be looking to output point x, y, z on rail2.

Many thanks.

Comment: Well, you will HAVE to loop through the segments.  Given the point, you have to find the matching segment in line 1 just so you can tell which direction is "perpendicular".  Then you have to loop through the segments of line 2 to see if a point 1.435m on either side is on or part of that segment.

Comment: Thank you. By specifying the point you will also be specifying the segment for line 1. Really the input will be a point along line 1, as opposed to an x, y, z. For instance a point at 100m on line 1.

Comment: I guess you could filter the coordinates of rail2 to show only those near to the specified point on rail2 and then loop through a smaller number of segments. I am hoping there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want the point of the minimum distance to the other track.

If the other track is defined by line segments, each spanning two points with a parameter **t** going between 0 and 1

```
pos(t) => pos_1 + t * ( pos_2 - pos_1 )
```

You need to find the **t** value that produces the minimum distance to the point. Place a temporary coordinate system on the point and express the ends of each line segment `pos_1` and `pos_2` in relative coordinates to the point of interest.

The value of **t** is for the closest point is

```
           dot(pos_1,pos_1) - dot(pos_1,pos_2)
t = ------------------------------------------------------
    dot(pos_1,pos_1)-2*dot(pos_1,pos_2)+dot(pos_2,pos_2)
```

where `dot(a,b)=ax*bx+ay*by+az*bz` is the vector dot product.

Now if the resulting **t** is between 0 and 1, then the closest point is on this segment, and its coordinates are given by

```
pos(t) => pos_1 + t * ( pos_2 - pos_1 )
```